# What is the encoding chosen by default when using the quick export method?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

In phpmyadmin, under export database, under export method there is option to choose quick or custom.

Custom allows to choose encoding. For quick, what is the encoding that is selected by default?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the "Character set of the file:" dropdown? That's the charset used for the generated export file (see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Export_charset).

The default is `utf-8`, but this can be changed and set explicitly in the configuration file `config.inc.php` through the directive `$cfg['Export']['charset'] = '';`.